# Is this set of $C[0,1]$ compact?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $x_1, x_2 \in C[0,1]$; $x_1(t)<x_2(t)$ $\forall t \in [0,1]$;

$$
M=\{x \in C[0,1]: x_1(t) \leq x(t) \leq x_2(t) \, \forall t \in [0,1]\}.
$$

Is $M$ compact or not?

Comment: I guess that you're considering $C[0,1]$ with the supremum norm. This turns $C[0,1]$ into a metric space. Now there are some useful characterizations of compactness in metric spaces, one of those is easy to use here.

Answer (score 4):

I take it you are asking for compactness in $C^0$

Then no, of course not, in particular not in this general setup. You can choose $x_1 = -2, x_2 = +2 $, then all functions $(\sin(\frac{kt}{2\pi}))_{k\in\mathbb{N}} $ and $(\cos(\frac{kt}{2\pi}))_{k\in\mathbb{N}} $ are in that set and it is known that each continuous functions may be approximated by (linear combinations of) them in $C^0$

Alternatively take the same $x_1, x_2$ and just look at the sequence $f_k(t) = t^k$, which is bounded but does not converge.

For general $x_1, x_2$ you can scale (add constants and multiply by constants) and use the same counterexample(s).

**Edit**: even simpler, take $f= \frac{x_1+x_2}{2}$ and $\delta :=  \frac{\min\{ x_2-x_1 \}}{2} > 0$. Then $B_\delta(f)$ is a full ball contained in $M$, which is never compact in infinite dimensions.